# Why does my Django request.method does not match POST

Tags: django

```
$.ajax({
    type :'GET',

    url : geturl(a),
    // type: $(this).attr('method'),
    dataType : 'json',
```

views.py:

```
  if request.method=="POST":


        if request.POST.get('monyrsubmit'):

            monthform=MonthForm(request.POST)
            if monthform.is_valid():
                selected_month=monthform.cleaned_data["Month"]
                selected_year=monthform.cleaned_data["Year"]
                print selected_month
                print selected_year
```

can i have both GET and POST requests in the type field of ajax. im using a form and only when the submit button is clicked im trying to display information based on the data submitted.  if request.POST.get('monyrsubmit') does not work. 
Help will be appreciated

Comment: Presumably you've tried it with `type: 'POST'` in the AJAX part? What do you see in the Firebug or Chrome Inspector network panel? My best guess is that you're hitting Django's CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You have to abstract the events.

```
function event_page_load() {
   function ajax_request('GET')
}

function click_submit_button() {
   function ajax_request('POST')
}

function ajax_request(type) {

 $.ajax({
    type : type,
    ......
    ......
 })
}
```

You can also consider the follwoign general guidelines.
GET and POST should be used based on the type of the request to the server

```
 - If you are reading the existing data(without modification) from the server, use GET
 - if you are writing/modifying any data in the server, use POST
```

in jQuery, you can use these simple methods.

For GET requests

```
$.get(  
    url,  
    {param1: "value1", param2: "value2"},  
    function(responseText){  
        // todo ;  
    },  
    "html"  
);
```

for POST requests

```
$.post(  
    url,  
    {param1: "value1", param2: "value2"},  
    function(responseText){  
        // todo ;  
    },  
    "html"  
);
```

Make sure that you have disable the browser caching.

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });
```

In django side, you can use `request.is_ajax()` method to verify the ajax call and you can filter based on `request.method` property.

You can refer all the possible usages of AJAX with Djano at https://github.com/sivaa/django-jquery-ajax-exmaples